# Do I need to use RecordSet.CancelUpdate when rolling back a transaction?

Tags: vb6

Please see the code below:

```
GenErr:
    If Err = -2147217871 Then
        'rs.CancelUpdate
        objCon.RollbackTransaction
        Resume AfterNes
    ElseIf Err = 3219 Then
        'rs.CancelUpdate
        objCon.RollbackTransaction
        Resume
    ElseIf Err = 9 Then
        Resume Next
    End If
           ImportUSNs = Error$
    Exit Function
    Resume
```

I have added a transaction today.  If I am rolling back the transaction (when there is an error) then do I need to call: rs.cancelupdate? rs is an ADO.Recordset.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681480(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Use the CancelUpdate method to cancel any changes made to the current
>   row or to discard a newly added row. You cannot cancel changes to the
>   current row or a new row after you call the Update method, unless the
>   changes are either part of a transaction that you can roll back with
>   the RollbackTrans method, or part of a batch update.

Since `RollbackTransaction` is going to roll everything back, `CancelUpdate` is unnecessary.